# How to run an aggregate query via mongo_go_driver that has javascript in it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, go, aggregate

I'm using the mongo-go-driver (https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo) and I'm trying to do the equivalent of

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
        from: "anothercollection",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "foreignID",
        as: "matched_docs"
    }},
    { $match: { "matched_docs": { $eq: [] } } },
    { $project: { "matched_docs": 0 } },
    { $match: {"dateTimeGMT":{$lt: (new Date(Date.now()-1000*60*60*24)).toISOString()}} }
])
```

I can't figure out how to put the Javascript commands in using this method.

```
pipeline := bson.NewArray(
    bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements( 
        //yada, yada, yada...
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
```

(In general, I dislike this method, anyway.  I want to be able to design queries in Robo 3T and copy them to my code just like I do with MySQL Workbench and PHP)

This method yields an empty *bson.Array in pipeline

```
pipelineJSON := `[
    { $lookup: {
        from: "anothercollection",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "interactionID",
        as: "matched_docs"
    }},
    { $match: { "matched_docs": { $eq: [] } } },
    { $project: { "matched_docs": 0 } },
    { $match: {"dateTimeGMT":{$lt: (new Date(Date.now()-1000*60*60*24)).toISOString()}} }
]`
pipeline, err = bson.ParseExtJSONArray(pipelineJSON)
```

I'd really love it if there were a way to send Mongo a command as a string (like I was typing it into Robo 3T) and get a *mongo.Cursor back.  Is there a better driver (that is still supported by someone) that I should use instead?  Do I need to code my own?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. You need to find an equivalent way of doing that in Go. That JS isn't anything special--it's just returning a date value a certain time in the past. Should be absolutely trivial to do the same without JS.

Comment: Flimzy: you are absolutely right that the JS isn't anything special and I can replace it with time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1).UTC().Format(time.RFC3339) in golang.  

To all: To clarify what I'm driving at, does anyone know where I can find documentation on the underlying mongodb api that the driver is using so I can determine if there is a javascript parser available at that level or only in the mongo shell?

Comment: Also, to clarify, the JS wasn't the only thing that worked in Robo3T/Mongo shell and failed in ParseExtJSONArray.  ParseExtJSONArray requires all the aggregation stages and functions be surrounded with quotes (instead of bare).  Is there a way for a client golang program to query mongo like the shell?

Comment: If your request is "Where do I find MongoDB docs?" the question is, unfortunately, off-topic here, as resource requests are off-topic. However, it should be easy to find MongoDB API docs.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose that the on-topic elements of my question are now resolved and I'm pivoting into off-topic.  I'll answer the question with what I've learned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to put the Javascript commands in using this method.

Although I understand this is not the preferred method for your use case, this is how to construct the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) as [bson.D](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) v1.0:

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$lookup", bson.D{
        {"from", "tour"}, 
        {"localField", "_id"}, 
        {"foreignField", "foreignID"}, 
        {"as", "matched_docs"},
    }}},
    {{"$match", bson.D{
        {"matched_docs", bson.D{
            {"$eq", bson.A{}}},
        }, 
    }}},
    {{"$project", bson.D{
        {"matched_docs", 0}, 
    }}},        
    {{"$match", bson.D{
        {"dateTimeGMT", bson.D{
            {"$lt", time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1).UTC().Format(time.RFC3339)},
            }, 
        },
    }}},  
}
```

> { $project: { "matched_docs": 0 } },

You can also combined the two `$match` into a single pipeline stage instead, and then attach `$project` at the end. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$lookup":{
        "from":"anothercollection",
        "localField":"_id",
        "foreignField":"foreignID",
        "as":"matched_docs"}
    }, 
    { "$match": { "matched_docs": { "$eq": [] }, 
                  "datetimegmt": { "$lt": (new Date(Date.now()-1000*60*60*24)).toISOString() } 
                } 
    }, 
    { "$project": { "matched_docs": 0 } }
]);
```

> { $match: {"dateTimeGMT":{$lt: (new Date(Date.now()-1000*60*60*24)).toISOString()}} }

Based on the `$match` value, it looks like you're storing date as `string` instead of a [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date) object. I would suggest to store dates as the proper `Date` objects for better index performance.

> Using ParseExtJSONArray DOES work, but, unlike Mongo Shell, you cannot include JS or unquoted aggregation stages / expression operators

[mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) shell provides some convienient methods/types i.e. `ObjectID()`, etc to construct [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-extended-json). The `mongo` shell is more than just a JavaScript shell.

If your aim just to evaluate a JavaScript expression, you can utilise a JavaScript interpreter for Go (otto). A rough example would be:

```
// Note the unquoted fields, as JSON is JavaScript native. 
raw := `[
    { "$lookup": {
        from: "anothercollection",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "foreignID",
        as: "matched_docs"
    }},
    { $match: { "matched_docs": { $eq: [] },
                "dateTimeGMT":{$lt: (new Date(Date.now()-1000*60*60*24)).toISOString() }, 
              }
    },
    { $project: { "matched_docs": 0 } },
]`
vm := otto.New()
// Evaluate JS expression
jsvalue, err := vm.Eval(raw)

// Export to Go interface{}
output, err := jsvalue.Export()

// Convert interface{} to bson.Document bytes 
bsonbytes, err := bson.Marshal(output)

// Convert bson.Document bytes to bson.Document
pipeline, err := bson.UnmarshalDocument(bsonbytes)
```

Note as mentioned above, there are some objects that will not be recognised by a normal JavaScript interpreter i.e. [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

> I want to be able to design queries in Robo 3T and copy them to my code just like I do with MySQL Workbench and PHP

Although currently does not support Go,  worth mentioning that [MongoDB Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/) has a feature to [Export Query to Language](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/export-query-to-language/). Current version (1.15) supports Java, Node, C# and Python3. Hopefully Go would be in the future.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've got a few clarifying questions. The first one has to do with the aggregation pipeline as a *bson.Document. Once I've constructed that *bson.Array, say I wanted to reuse it and just change the date. Is there an easy way to get at it or do I have to construct and iterator and make a few Lookup() calls? Would it be easier to just construct the whole thing every time? (or assemble the *bson.Array from partially constructed pieces).

Comment: The 2nd question has to do with your suggestion that I use a Date object instead of a date string. I can't put ISODate("...") in the string for the ParseExtJSONArray approach. I've learned that ISODate("...") exports to {"$date":"..."}, but if I put that in the JSON string and try to $match on dateTimeGMT.$date, it doesn't work. Is the *bson.Document approach my only option to work with date objects instead of date as a string?

Comment: Make that two questions.

Comment: 1) Normally you construct the `bson.Document` per stage, then assemble into a single `bson.Array` before sending into aggregation. So you can construct just the `$match` document instead of all of the stages.

Comment: 2) that should work. `ParserExtJSONArray` should be able to understand extended JSON format `$date`, could you open a new question with examples and post the link here.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks!

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276568/date-match-aggregate-stage-not-working-with-parserextjsonarray-in-mongo-go-driv

Answer (score 2):

Using ParseExtJSONArray DOES work, but, unlike Mongo Shell, you cannot include JS or unquoted aggregation stages / expression operators.  Note that the ISO date for the comparison is calculated in golang and the aggregation stages and aggregtion expression operators have been surrounded by quotes.

```
pipelineJSON := fmt.Sprintf(`[
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "another_collection",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "interactionID",
        "as": "matched_docs"
    }},
    { "$match": { "matched_docs": { "$eq": [] } } },
    { "$project": { "matched_docs": 0 } },
    { "$match": {"dateTimeGMT":{"$lt": "%s"}} }
]`, time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1).UTC().Format(time.RFC3339))
pipeline, err = bson.ParseExtJSONArray(pipelineJSON)
```

With the driver I asked about, that's the answer.